# execute at specific time

Tags: linux

1. create a file
2. change its permissions at a specific time
3. change the permission.

At the moment this is what I have and it changes the permissions of the file but not according to the time specified.

```
#!/bin/bash 
$ at 13:05 
chmod 777 bin/permission.sh
```

Comment: 1.  Please break your description into sentences.  2.  Please post your first attempt at writing this script.  3.  Please include any problems you're having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make a file executable at 3pm, you can do:

```
echo chmod 777 /path/to/file | at 3pm
```

The `at` command takes a script on its standard input. So you echo the command you want to run into `at` and tell `at` when to run it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [crontab](http://crontab.org)

```
crontab -e
```

And write:

```
05 13 * * * chmod 0777 /full/path/to/bin/permission.sh
```

supposing you want it to be executed **everyday** at 13:05. Finally, save the file.

NOTE: The default editor seems to be "vi", if you are not comfortable with this you can change it before executing "crontab -e" with:

```
export EDITOR=nano
```

for example.

Comment: Heh, I highly doubt that emacs will be easier to use than vim. Maybe nano would be a better choice?

Comment: I agree, edited now.